# Socket timeout exception with connection on Android

Tags: android, connection, socket-timeout-exception

I have this code to test a connection to an https url:

```
    cTimerTask = new Timer();
    cTimerTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {   
try {
URL myUrl = new URL("https://www.google.it");
                            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                            connection.connect();
                            Log.d(TAG, "!!! responsecode: " + connection.getResponseCode());

                            //Log.d(TAG, "connection ok");

                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "!!! Malformed URL");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
     }

            }
        }, GlobalClass.DELAY_CONNECTION_CHECK, GlobalClass.PERIOD_CONNECTION_CHECK);
```

Sometimes (not always) something is wrong and I have SocketTimeoutException, but I have no problem connection, internet is working well. I have used this code for a long time, but in the last week I have this problem.

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.google.it/216.58.210.195 (port 443) after 15000ms
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you directly ping the IP and check if you are receiving any response!!

Comment: thx! It seems to be work better now! I've done a test check with % packet loss from a ping to the IP